# How can I read from a text file, reverse every word but not their places, and then write it into another text file?

Tags: c

lets say we have an input text file and an empty output text file. The program supposed to reverse every word in the input file but not their places then write it in the output file.
How can I obtain the following output?

input:

bacon is tasty and crispy.

Orange is overrated.

output:

nocab si ytsat dna ypsirc.

Egrango si detarrevo.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not going to just provide an answer, this looks like homework. The way I would approach it is:

*Interesting* characters are : `'\n'` and `' '`.

1. Ready char by char
2. Check if you have encountered any *interesting* characters
3. If you have not, store the character read into an array
4. If you have, print the array (make sure its not empty), starting from the last character saved.
5. Go to 1 (until EOF)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't looking for a code answer actually, I was looking for the logic of the solution and you provided it!